# Weak-linking with static libraries

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, weak-linking

I have declared an external function with a GCC weak attribute in a .c file:

```
extern int weakFunction( ) __attribute__ ((weak));
```

Compiled object file has weakFunction defined as a weak symbol.
Output of nm:

```
1791:         w weakFunction
```

I am calling the weak defined function as follows:

```
if (weakFunction != NULL)
{
    weakFunction();
}
```

When I link the program by defining the object files as parameters to GCC (`gcc main.o weakf.o -o main.exe`) weak symbols work fine. If I leave the weakf.o out of linking, the function address is NULL in main.c and the function won't be called.

Problem is, when weakf.o is inside a static library, for some reason the linker doesn't find the function and the function address always ends up being NULL.
Static library is created with ar: `ar rcs weaklibrary weakf.o`

Anyone had similar problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I don't know the exact workings of weak symbols it looks like you are getting what you ask for: if no one else is forcing the weakFunction() to be present, main() won't either. To me this makes sense: if you are trying to write code which works with facility X present as well as without it, then you don't want your code to force X to be included in your build at all costs. It looks like "weak" is meant to ask *if* something is present, not to request *that* something is present.
Maybe you can force inclusion of weak symbols with "-u weakFunction" as linker option in your case.

Comment: Thanks, this information helped. For now, I will use --whole-archive parameter until I find a better way to force symbols to be linked. -u parameter didn't work :(.