# No linker error when static library calls weak function with no implementation

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, clang, static-libraries

The overall problem I am trying to solve:

I would like a library statically-linked to my application, to call a function within my application. However, when the library is compiled and installed, it obviously doesn't know about my application.

I thought I could achieve this by including the function name (the one I intend to implement within my application) within the library and declaring it as weak:

lib_file.h:

```
__attribute__((weak)) int weak_func(int x, int y);

void func();
```

lib_file.c:

```
void func()
{
    weak_func(6, 7);  // Want this to call function implemented in my app
}
```

This compiles and links successfully and I re-install the library.

However, my application also compiles and links successfully, even though I haven't implemented the function yet.

Is this expected? I was expecting the linker to complain and I have to add an implementation for `weak_func()` within my application.

Is what I am trying to achieve possible?

UPDATE

After following the advice from TianpingHsu I copied his self-contained example, having the two files above and app.c:

```
#include "./lib_file.h"

int main() 
{
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately when I compile and link:

```
gcc -c -o libfunc.o lib_file.c
ar rcs libfunc.a libfunc.o
gcc app.c -lfunc -L./
```

it produces no linker warnings:

[image]

and generates the executable:

[image]

Running `nm` on the library shows no address:

[image]

whereas TianpingHsu gets `u weak_func`.

My platform is `gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0`

Comment: maybe this one? [https://stackoverflow.com/a/70093269/5391421](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70093269/5391421) in the last paragraph.

Comment: @JakkapongRattananen That paragraph implies there is a fallback implementation? Here there isn't. Under `nm` the address is undefined, so a segmentation fault occurs.

Answer (score 1):

*Update*
yeah, I see your [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77540650/compilers-allow-a-weak-symbol-function-with-no-implementation-and-no-linker-erro), and Employed Russian's answer is right.

*Upadte*
@rare77, source code of `lib_file.c` in the question does not include the header file `lib_file.h`, and you will get `U weak_func` from `lib_file.o` after `gcc -c -o libfunc.o lib_file.c`. It seems that you don't need to use **attribute**((weak)), just declare a normal function `weak_func` in your static library and provide your implementation in you app. And if you don't provide your `weak_func` in your app, you will get linkage error.

P.S.
I add `#include "lib_file.h"` line into my lib_file.c, and indeed I do get `w weak_func` from `nm lib_file.o`. if you want to get linkage error in this way, you can use `-u` option of gcc, however, it seems unnecessary.

Original Post
Maybe there's something wrong with your linkage, say you don't link with your weak version static library, or you don't call the `func` in your app at all.

If you do things right, when you link the library, the linker will complain that `weak_func` is not implemented with message: `undefined reference to *weak_func*`. please check the whole procedure.

Here's my test on my WSL:

> ~/sandbox$ ls
> app.c  lib_file.c  lib_file.h

build the static library:

> ~/sandbox$ gcc -c -o libfunc.o lib_file.c
> lib_file.c: In function ‘func’:
> lib_file.c:3:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘weak_func’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
> 3 |     weak_func(6, 7);  // Want this to call function implemented in my app
> |     ^~~~~~~~~
> ~/sandbox$ ar rcs libfunc.a libfunc.o

link with app:

> ~/sandbox$ gcc app.c -lfunc -L./
> /usr/bin/ld: .//libfunc.a(libfunc.o): in function `func':   lib_file.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to` weak_func'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

here's the `app.c`:

```
#include "./lib_file.h"

int main() {
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

my platform:

> Linux Abstraction 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #3636-Microsoft Thu Oct 19 17:41:00 PST 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I've ran `nm` on the library and it shows the weak function. So the problem must be with my application linking. Not sure what the problem is, given it does still compile and link!

Comment: I've ran `nm` on my application binary and it shows the same as the library, `w weak_func` with no address. Is the lack of an address kinda proving it never linked successfully (even though there wasn't an error)?

Comment: @rare77 Pressing the checkmark on an answer indicates that you don't need any more help.

Comment: @rare77 if your app binary has `weak_func` and it has no address, you will get crash if your app calls `func`.  Are you sure your app calls the `func` of the library? because if you don't call `func`, the linker will never link the symbol, which means you can link successfully even though you do not implement the `weak_func` in you app code.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure, I've just stepped through the code, it's calling `weak_func()` and then I get a segmentation fault. It's like if the linker just isn't doing it's job (not saying this is the likely reason).

Comment: can you try my tiny example above on your platform and check weather we have the same behavior?

Comment: So I copied your commands and it's let me produce the application binary.

Comment: To confirm, I did: 1) `gcc -c -o libfunc.o lib_file.c` 2) `ar rcs libfunc.a libfunc.o` and 3) `gcc app.c -lfunc -L./` It's given me a file named `a.out*`

Comment: my gcc version: gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0

Comment: My GCC Is 11.4.0 on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Going to up-vote all your comments for additional rep, as I have no idea what the problem is and I appreciate your help.

Comment: not figured out yet. a solution to avoid clash: `if (weak_func) weak_func(x, y);`

Comment: @TianpingHsu I've added a few screenshots to my question showing the unexpected linker success.

Comment: when I run `nm` on my `libfunc.a`, I get `U weak_func`, maybe different versions of gcc or diffrent compilers have different behavior. check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203402/gcc-behavior-for-unresolved-weak-functions

Comment: When I run `nm` on `libfunc.a` I get `w weak_func`

Comment: @TianpingHsu When I look at my original application and run `nm` on the static library, that also has `w weak_func`, the same discrepancy we are seeing now. However, that was compiled using Clang, not GCC.

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588983/what-does-the-gnu-ld-undefined-option-do

Comment: @TianpingHsu If I run `gcc app.c -u -lfunc -L./` I get `"app.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to 'func'"`. Is this what we want? I thought it would have been weak_func

Comment: try this? ` --require-defined` (`man ld`)

Comment: @TianpingHsu `gcc app.c --require-defined=weak_func -lfunc -L./` ? I'm not sure how I'm supposed to supply that new flag

Comment: @rare77 does this work: `gcc app.c -u weak_func -lfunc -L ./` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627839/weak-linking-with-static-libraries I'll check on my Linux PC when I am home.

Comment: @TianpingHsu It works BUT the only problem is, that assumes I know the symbol name. Is there any way without knowing the symbols?