# Compilers allow a weak symbol function with no implementation and no linker error

Tags: gcc, linker, clang, static-libraries, static-linking

A static library declares a function with a weak symbol.

Later an application (not providing the function implementation)  statically links the library but no linker error is generated.

This seems to occur with both GCC 11.4 and Clang 16.

This was discovered when asking:

[No linker error when static library calls weak function with no implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77540318/no-linker-error-when-static-library-calls-weak-function-with-no-implementation)

Example:

lib_file.h:

```
__attribute__((weak)) int weak_func(int x, int y);

void func();
```

lib_file.c:

```
#include "lib_file.h"

void func()
{
    weak_func(6, 7);  // Want this to call function implemented in my app
}
```

app.c:

```
#include "./lib_file.h"

int main() 
{
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and link:

```
gcc -c -o libfunc.o lib_file.c
ar rcs libfunc.a libfunc.o
gcc app.c -lfunc -L./
```

On my system gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0 this generates the application executable successfully.

Running `nm` on the library:

[image]

However, someone else using GCC 9.4 gets `u weak_func`.

I then run my application and get a segmentation fault.

Is this correct? It feels like a silent failure.

Comment: This question appears to be exact duplicate of your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this correct? It feels like a silent failure.

Yes, this is working as intended: a weak reference *does not* cause a link failure (and also does not cause the linker to pull a defining object from an archive library).

> I then run my application and get a segmentation fault.

The usual way to call an optionally-provided function is:

```
void func()
{
  if (&weak_func != NULL)
    weak_func(6, 7);  // Call weak_func if one has been provided.
}
```

If *not* providing `weak_func` is an error that you want to be detected at link time, then don't declare the required function `weak`.

In your other question you said:

> when the library is compiled and installed, it obviously doesn't know about my application.

You appear to be under misconception that the archive library needs to know anything about your application. It *doesn't* -- simply remove the `weak` attribute and everything will just work(TM).

More precisely, without the `weak` attribute:

- your archive library will compile and install just fine
- if your app defines the function elsewhere, the link will succeed and the library will call your function
- if your app does not define the function, the link will fail

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've got the library compiling now. May I ask: in my application, I've put the definition of `int weak_func(int x, int y){ return 0; }` in a header but I'm getting the linker undefined reference error. Do I need to put the definition in a source file, or use `extern` etc?

Comment: @rare77 The problem is that your `weak_func` will be defined in every `.o` where the header is `#include`d. You'll want to _declare_ the function in the header, but _define_ it in the source file.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still having issues. I can't `nm` my application binary because the error stops it being generated. Is there anything else I can do to debug this? Is there any way I can "see" what symbols from my app the compiler and linker are seeing, without the binary?

Comment: @rare77 It's best to ask a new question. Provide the minimal example and show compile commands and the error you observe.